# Django / Heroku application Error when switching from sqlite to posgresql's heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm running a Django app on Heroku everything's going great but when I try to switch to Heroku's database I get an application error.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Code I added that broke things

import dj_database_url 
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600) 
if db_from_env: DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env) 
else : DATABASES = {'default'}
```

Heroku logs

```
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566720+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566726+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566726+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566726+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566727+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566727+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566727+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566727+00:00 app[web.1]: with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566727+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566727+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566728+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566728+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566728+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_random_link" does not exist
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566728+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...om_link"."id", "accounts_random_link"."link" FROM "accounts_...
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566728+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566728+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.566934+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 16:28:06 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568949+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 16:28:06 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568950+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568950+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568950+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568950+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "accounts_random_link" does not exist
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568951+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...om_link"."id", "accounts_random_link"."link" FROM "accounts_...
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568951+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568951+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568952+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568961+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568962+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568962+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568962+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568963+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568963+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568963+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568964+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568964+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568964+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568964+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568964+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568965+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/src/Planningator/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568967+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568967+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568967+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568967+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568967+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568968+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config.import_models()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568968+00:00 app[web.1]: self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568968+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568970+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/src/accounts/models.py", line 15, in <module>
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568970+00:00 app[web.1]: entry_list = list(Random_Link.objects.all())
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568970+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568970+00:00 app[web.1]: self._fetch_all()
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568970+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568970+00:00 app[web.1]: self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568971+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568971+00:00 app[web.1]: results = compiler.execute_sql(
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568972+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568976+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568976+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568976+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568976+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568977+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568978+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_random_link" does not exist
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568978+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...om_link"."id", "accounts_random_link"."link" FROM "accounts_...
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568978+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-05-09T16:28:06.568978+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-09T16:28:06.569136+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 16:28:06 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-05-09T16:28:06.677336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/take_me_to_internet" host=internet-simulator.herokuapp.com request_id=a567d31d-7fee-46cc-b9c9-795302b31746 fwd="86.250.184.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=137ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-05-09T16:28:06.683212+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 16:28:06 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-05-09T16:28:06.778732+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 16:28:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-05-09T16:28:06.778784+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 16:28:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-05-09T16:28:06.945547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-05-09T16:28:07.059170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I also tried migrating from `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, which gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "accounts_random_link" does not exist
LINE 1: ...om_link"."id", "accounts_random_link"."link" FROM "accounts_...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/src/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/src/accounts/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    entry_list = list(Random_Link.objects.all())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_random_link" does not exist
LINE 1: ...om_link"."id", "accounts_random_link"."link" FROM "accounts_...
```

Comment: I think it's conflicting with you sqlite and postgres database try to add your database using condition like this `if db_from_env: you_postgres_db_cnf else : sqlite`

Comment: I'm kinda new to this by you_postgres_db_cnf u mean name of my heroku posgre db?

Comment: Yes, @Dastfox try to add it inside condition

Comment: i did this 
```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
if db_from_env: DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
else : DATABASES = {'default'}
```
And gor server eror (500)

Comment: Can you add this code inside your question by making an [edit]

Comment: Done (thank you for this help its really cool!)

Comment: I understand that you're frustrated, but please avoid profanity.

Comment: Side note that shouldn't affect you on Heroku, but may affect you locally: the `else` here doesn't do what you think it does: `else : DATABASES = {'default'}`—this sets `DATABASES` to a _set_ that contains one value, the string `'default'`. Better to leave the `else` off entirely so the previous setting remains intact. (Better still to switch to Postgres for local development. SQLite and Postgres aren't drop-in replacements for each other, and I've seen real-world situations where applications blow up in production due to the differences.)

Comment: Have you ever migrated this Postgres databases successfully? Alternatively, did you try to copy data from SQLite into it, or otherwise modify the migrations table? Have you squashed migrations?

Comment: sotrry i'll be more carefull with my language np ! Don't have the codes yet :p)

Comment: I tried switching to posgres. I succeded in local but was having a hard time pushing it to heroku. (f'u have a tuto or doc i'm interested !)
i removed the else con, squased and migrated successfully but the app got error 500 It's running locally without problems  and when i comment the "db_from_env etc" it works perfectly else it leads me to error 500